# Do Gradle support building multiple java modules in a single project?

Tags: java, gradle, java-platform-module-system

I'm developing two applications which both share a common library-project, and the three projects are organized under a gradle multiproject. The common project includes the public API at the time and my idea was to use the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) to make the public API a single module to distribute. I do not want to distribute my whole common library, as it contains implementations and my internal API. Turning the entire common library into a module was fairly easy following [these guidelines](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html).

However, I wanted to split this project into two java modules, one for the public api and one for the internal api, and this is where my troubles begin. From what I've learned, a modular JAR may only consist of at most one module, however there is no restriction on declaring multiple modules in a single project (as Java is probably not even aware of the *project* concept). According to [this blog](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html), it is done by adding a folder for each module under `src/main/java`, and let it contain the `module-info.java` for that module).

When I tried this in my gradle project, my added "module folder" (e.g. `foo.bar`) was interpreted as an ordinary package. I assume that this happens as all modules reside in the same source set.

The simple and quick solution for my problem would of course be to create a new subproject containing the public API. However it seems a little bit unpractical, if I were to perform further modularization down the road. From what I can tell there certainly is no need for a 1-to-1 mapping between gradle projects and java modules.

My plain question is if it is possible for gradle (e.g. via plugin) to automatically identify the modules and build one modular jar for each declared module?

Comment: Actually, the way Gradle approaches it, the proper thing to do is create a sub-project for each module. This is what you would have done before JPMS anyway.

Comment: That was my fallback solution. I just thought that it added redundant code to maintain in form of the gradle.build scripts.

Comment: When you have multiple sub-projects sharing build configurations you should extract that configuration out into one place. There are multiple ways of doing this: `subprojects { ... }`, `buildSrc`, scripts, full-on plugins, and so on. Here's an example using `buildSrc`: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

Comment: For now I'll go with the `subprojects{ ... }` to make all common settings and it works well, I would say. However, it still feels like this solution somewhat cripples the qualified export function of JPMS, as e.g. a library java module is unaware of any other modules and thus give warnings upon compilation.

Comment: You can always add a `compileOnly(project("..."))` dependency to the project which has a qualified exports.

Comment: At first glance, it seems to solve the problem. However, in my case it yields a circular dependency. Say I have Library A to be used by App B and App C. I cannot have library A to `compileOnly project('App B')` and App B to `implementation project ('Library A')`. It works without using `compileOnly`, but I get warnings which is clearly not satisfiable.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Unfortunately the philosophy of Gradle (and Maven) is that each (sub-)project maps to one JAR file. And JPMS only allows one module per JAR file, at least for now. I suppose you _could_ write a plugin that makes use of `--module-source-path` and `--module` when compiling; there may even be one already out there (though I'd be somewhat surprised). But I'm not sure such a plugin could coexist with the built-in `java` plugin. Also keep in mind that Gradle only became properly JPMS-aware with version 6.4 (i.e. not too long ago, and years after Java 9 was released).

Comment: Luckily though you only get a warning, and not an error, for qualified exports/opens to modules that aren't present.

Comment: I'll stick with the one-to-one project to jar mapping in my project for now then and it's not that big issue in my case. The JPMS is a revolutionary change in the Java ecosystem, so maybe it takes some time to adapt to a completely new scenario. I'll guess that the projects built using JPMS fully from scratch has not been that many (or impacting) to issue a rewrite of the well established `java` plugin. Eventually this function will be incorporated, for sure.